# Use of spread properties throws unexpected token issue

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, webpack-2

I know there are many answers for this questions existing already. But nothing fixed my issue.

I am using redux for my react application and transpiling ES6 and JSX using babel. When I used spread properties in redux like so:

```
return {...state, loading: false}
```

my webpack is throwing unexpected token issue. I have used stage-0, stage-2 presents (not both at same time). Also tried transform-es2015-destructuring and transform-object-rest-spread plugins.
Surprisingly, stage-0 worked for one of my other projects but not for the current project. I am curious to know the exact issue.
Here is my webpack configuration:

```
const config = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, PATHS.entry),
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, PATHS.output),
    filename: 'bundle.[hash].js'
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [{
            loader: "style-loader"
          },{
            loader: "css-loader"
          }, {
            loader: "sass-loader"
        }],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        loaders: [
          'file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=images/[hash].[ext]',
          'image-webpack-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: "./src/index.html"
  })]
};
```

This is my babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-2"]
}
```

Comment: It's not ES6 code indeed. Stage-0 should work, but are you sure that webpack respects your babel configuration? Please show us your config files and the invocation of the tools.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "spread operator". `...` is not an operator.

Comment: What file are you using it in? Does it have a `.jsx` extension?

Comment: @MichaelJungo, Thank you. So bad of me that i haven't changed my webpack config to consider js files. This is fixed.